# TinyMCE 4 Link List dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

Hi I'm migrating TinyMCE to v 4 in a bespoke CMS. I'm trying to create a drop-down list of links using the links plugin with a generated link_list but can't make it work.

The code looks like this:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "#editor",
plugins: [
    ["advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor spellchecker"],
    ["searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"],
    ["save table contextmenu template paste textcolor"]
],
link_list: [
  {title: "HOME", value: "/"},
  {title: "Footer Content", value: "/footer-content/"},
  {title: "Employee Survey", value: "/employee-survey/"},
  {title: "NEWS", value: "/news/"},
  {title: "2 Col Simple", value: "/2-col-simple/"},
  {title: "2 Col 2", value: "/2-col-2/"},
  {title: "2 Col 3", value: "/2-col-3/"},
  {title: "2 Col", value: "/2-col/"},
  {title: "CONTACT US", value: "/contact-us/"}
],
theme: "modern",
inline: true,
resize: "both",
menubar: false,
fixed_toolbar_container: "#test_menu",       
toolbar1: "bold italic underline outdent indent alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify undo redo hr code link unlink image forecolor backcolor numlist bullist addimage", 
toolbar2: "fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect formatselect table",
```

Whilst the editor works, it doesn't create the drop-down I was expecting from inserting the link_list..

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Phil